# Why are the sides of my cube not displaying?

Tags: opengl

I would like to display 5 sides of a box (only the top side is not shown) extending from -(-50, -50, -50) to (50, 50, 50). My cube-drawing function is as follows:

```
void drawRectangularPrism(Coordinate corner, Coordinate dimensions)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // back face
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    // bottom face
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    // top face
    glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    // right face
    glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x + dimensions.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    // left face
    glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z + dimensions.z);
    glVertex3f(corner.x, corner.y + dimensions.y, corner.z);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

And in case it is useful, here is my function that sets up the OpenGL rendering:

```
void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Clear the background of our window to white
    GLfloat specular[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, shininess[] = {50.0}, emission[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        lightPosition[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, lightAmbient[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        lightDiffuse[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, lightSpecular[] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shininess);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, emission);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // makes objects overlap correctly / or not?!
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // makes it faster?!
}
```

The final result:

[image: well something's wrong!]

Why aren't the top and left sides of the cube being displayed?

Comment: Have you tried drawing each side individually to figure out which side isn't being drawn as you expect?

Comment: @DavidBrown What do you mean? By commenting all but one side, to see if it really isn't being drawn? Then yes, it turns out every single side is still being drawn when drawn alone, except for the left and top faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Top / Bottom, Left / Right face pairs only vary by an offset, which suggests you haven't considered vertex winding order. Look at `glFrontFace` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your quads are most likely culled away by

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Remove it and it should work